# How to access percent as props in custom label function in bar chart of recharts?

Tags: recharts

In pie charts, we can access value as well as percent in props of a custom label function assigned for the label prop in pie component. But in bar charts, I can only get value but not percent in props of a custom label function assigned for a bar component label. I am trying to show the percent instead of values in stacked bar chart.

Is there a way to do that?

Now when I tried to get percent from the props, undefined is what I get. I console logged the prop of the custom label function and it does not have a percent.